# ViewScoped Beans still permanently recreated under JSF 2.2

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2

As stated in many posts here (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812238/jsf-view-scoped-bean-reconstructed-multiple-times)), the problem of ViewScoped beans being recreated over and over again should be gone with JSF 2.2.

So I have udated to MyFaces 2.2 and changed the imports in my view scoped beans to:

```
package javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyView {
    ....
}
```

But still the ViewScoped Beans behave even worse than RequestSqoped Beans - the @PostConstruct method is run through several times on view creation and on every interaction with the page.

The JSR299 dependencies are:

- weld 1.1.Final
- wel-core 1.1.14.Final
- codi 1.0.5

The jsp/servlet version read like:

- javax.servlet-api 3.0.1
- jsp-api 2.2

Has anyone made ViewScope work as designed under MyFaces 2.2 and CODI?

Comment: IIRC there's still a chicken-and-egg issue if you reference the `@ViewScoped` bean in a view build time tag. But I've no idea if this applies to JSP, too.

Comment: ViewScoped is JSF specific. Post relevant facelet.

Comment: Also make sure you're running a CDI 1.1 implementation.  Weld 1.1 is a CDI 1.0 impl, use Weld 2.x, preferably latest.