# @PostConstruct method of @ViewScoped bean is called two times on page refresh

Tags: jsf, view-scope, postconstruct

I have a bean called `indexBean` and it has an `init` method. My bean is set to be `ViewScoped`.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    ...
    System.out.println("entered");
    ...
}
```

Why the `init()` method is called twice when I refresh the page?

Comment: Probably I have same problem but couldnt solve yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add additional informations, e.g. JSF Version. Do you have a JSF @ManagedBean or something else like CDI @named bean. In the latter case, you might run into trouble using different cdi-frameworks, see for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812238/jsf-view-scoped-bean-reconstructed-multiple-times)